# ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build

Tags: docker, workspace

W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.

W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.

E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' is no longer signed.

ERROR:

> Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
>   update -yqq && pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && groupadd -g ${PGID}
>   laradock && useradd -u ${PUID} -g laradock -m laradock -G docker_env
>   && usermod -p "*" laradock' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: Could you add more information? What have you executed? Your commands, dockerfile...etc?

Comment: Docker version ($ docker --version): 17.09.0-ce
Laradock commit ($ git rev-parse HEAD): master
System info (Mac, PC, Linux): Mac

Answer (score 0):

I try it

git checkout -b v6.0.1 v6.0.1

cp env-example .env